# No adapter attached; skipping layout (Recyclerview)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want display pictures from firebase realtime database. (with Encryted image(String))
like [Encrypted Image is "photo"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAAK.png)

I run this app recyclerview didn't appear with error code

> No adapter attached; skipping layout

ItemObject.java

```
    public class ItemObject {
    
            private String title;
            private String Photo;
    
            public String getTitle() {
                return title;
            }
    
            public void setTitle(String title) {
                this.title = title;
            }
    
            public String getPhoto() {
                return Photo;
            }
    
            public void setPhoto(String photo){
    
                this.Photo=photo;
            }
    
            public ItemObject(String title, String photo) {
            this.title = title;
            this.Photo=photo;
            }
            public ItemObject() {}
    
        }

Recyclerview adpater MyAdapter.java

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<ItemObject> mItem;
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mListener = null;



    public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnCreateContextMenuListener {

         TextView title;
         ImageView imageView;
     //   private CardView cardView;


        public RecyclerViewHolders(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.title =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_listitem);
            this.imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_listitem);

//
            itemView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);


        }


    private final MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener onEditMenu = new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case 1001:
                    mItem.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), mItem.size());

                    break;
            }
            return true;

        }
    };

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            MenuItem Delete = menu.add(Menu.NONE,1001,1,"삭제");
            Delete.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onEditMenu);
        }
    }


        public MyAdapter(ArrayList<ItemObject> item){
             this.context = context;
             this.mItem = item;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem,viewGroup,false);
        RecyclerViewHolders viewHolders=new RecyclerViewHolders(view);
        return viewHolders;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
      /*  Glide.with(context)
                .load(mItem.get(position).getPhoto())
                .into(holder.imageView);

       */
        ItemObject itemObject = mItem.get(position);
        String photo = itemObject.getPhoto();
        holder.title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,10);
        holder.title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        holder.title.setText(itemObject.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(photo));
//       Glide.with(this.context).load(mItem.get(position).getPhoto()).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);



    }

    public void setmItem(ArrayList<ItemObject> mItem) {
        this.mItem = mItem;
    }


    public void deleteItem(int position) {

            mItem.remove(position);

            notifyItemRemoved(position);



    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItem.size();
    }
}
```

MainUpload.java

```
mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_main_list);
        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplication(),numberOfColumns);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mItem = new ArrayList<>();

        //clearAll();
        loadPhoto();


        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration=new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(),mGridLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), mRecyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                ItemObject itemObject = mItem.get(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",itemObject.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("photo",itemObject.getPhoto());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
            }
        }));
```

function loadPhoto()

```
   private void loadPhoto() {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getInstance().getReference("users")
                .child(currentUser.getUid()).child("Object").getKey();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                .child(currentUser.getUid()).child("Object").child(key);
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_main_list);
                    int numberOfColumns = 3;
                    GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplication(),numberOfColumns);
                    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
                    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

                    ItemObject itemObject = new ItemObject();
                    //여기서 에러
                    String En1 = snapshot.child("photo").getValue().toString();
                    byte []En2 = En1.getBytes();
                    AESCoderAndriod aesCoderAndriod = new AESCoderAndriod();
                    try {
                        byte []Dn1 = aesCoderAndriod.decrypt(seed,En2);
                        Bitmap Dn2 = byteArrayToBitmap(Dn1);
                        Uri Dn3 = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),Dn2);
                        itemObject.setPhoto(Dn3.toString());
                        itemObject.setTitle(snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString());
                        mItem.add(itemObject);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    //   itemObject.setPhoto(snapshot.child("Photo").getValue().toString());

                }
                //myAdapter= new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mItem);
               // mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mItem);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
```

what is the problem? I connect adapter and recyclerview, and set gridmanager.

Comment: Just set the adapter to your recycle view.

Comment: I set Adapter in loadPhoto() << mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Answer (score 0):

You should set your adapter at first, Start with empty recycler view, when data loads you should notify your adapter about the change.

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mItem = new ArrayList<>();
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mItem);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
loadPhoto();
```

You function already include notify data change method. You don't need to set new layout manager on data load method

```
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ItemObject itemObject = new ItemObject();
                    //여기서 에러
                    String En1 = snapshot.child("photo").getValue().toString();
                    byte []En2 = En1.getBytes();
                    AESCoderAndriod aesCoderAndriod = new AESCoderAndriod();
                    try {
                        byte []Dn1 = aesCoderAndriod.decrypt(seed,En2);
                        Bitmap Dn2 = byteArrayToBitmap(Dn1);
                        Uri Dn3 = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(),Dn2);
                        itemObject.setPhoto(Dn3.toString());
                        itemObject.setTitle(snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString());
                        mItem.add(itemObject);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    //   itemObject.setPhoto(snapshot.child("Photo").getValue().toString());

                }
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but It still have same error message <<No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Ah! No error but it can not display image from database....

Comment: just before notifying the adapter about the change, please check with a log that you can get the items from the db. You can log the size of the mItem list. Now you don't have the error about the recycler view attaching but something else